# « Arriver des premiers » : usage

Tags: expressions, usage, france

*La Petite Fadette*, George Sand

> Enfin vint le dimanche, et Landry arriva des
> premiers à la messe.

1. « Des premiers » est une forme très courante au 19<sup>e</sup> siècle et avant. Il me semble  que ce serait peu utilisé dans la langue d'aujourd'hui, ou même pas du tout ; est-ce exact ?
2. Une expression moderne de remplacement est sans nul doute  « *dans les premiers* ».  En existe-il une autre qui soit préférable ou plus élégante ?
3. Est-ce que quelqu'un aurait une idée de pourquoi, à la concision de « des premiers » une préférence pour des expressions plus longues a pris le dessus ?

Comment: ***parmi*** les premiers — *des* vs *dès*

Comment: @Personne Je connais bien « parmi les premiers » et je pense que ce n'est ni mieux ni moins bien que « dans les premiers », même si « parmi » s'emploie rarement, mais peut-être  trouvez-vous une  différence.

Comment: Pour le langage populaire, *être dans* s'entend *être **de**dans*, avec toutes les possibilités que la grivoiserie offre… en revanche, les enfants le disent, c'est familier aussi. Pour Georges Sand, la substitution d'un mot oublié se calligraphie avec *parmi*.